# Calling user specified R function in inline C++ body

Tags: r, inline, armadillo

I have been working with the R package "RcppArmadillo". I already used it to define two cxxfunction(they have been debugged are fine to use):

```
calc1 <- cxxfunction(signature(A="integer", B="integer"),...)
calc2 <- cxxfunction(signature(A="integer", K="integer"),...)
```

Now I'm writing the body part of another cxxfunction main and wish to call calc1 and calc2 within the for loops there, like:

```
body_main = '

    ...
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        // This is where I want to call calc1.
        // (?)
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
             // This is where I want to call calc2.
             // (?)
        }
    }

'
```

Is there anyway that I can achieve that? Can that be done in an inline fashion?

I haven't seen an example of inline usage of RcppArmadillo(or Rcpp, RcppGSL) in which people write a subroutine within the body part - specifically, I mean code looks like this:

```
body_example = '

    // Subroutine
    SEXP(/*or something else*/) func_0(SEXP A, SEXP B){
        ...
        return ...;
    }

    // Then call it from the main part
    ...
    AB = func_0(A, B);
    ...
'
```

My question probably looks naive but it haunts me nevertheless. Can anyone help explain this? I'd appreciate that a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch from using `cxxfunction()` from package [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) to using Rcpp attributes and its `sourceCpp()`.  That way you get the predictable function headers at the C++ level, see the Rcpp atributes vignette.

Or split `calc1` and `calc2` into 'worker' and 'wrapper', have `cxxfunction()` around the wrapper allowing you to call the worker.

The key issue here really is that `cxxfunction()` exists to create an *R-callable* function, and it generates internal randomized function headers.

Lastly, a package would help too.

Comment: Many thanks, Dirk! I believe sourceCpp should work for my case - but may I further ask that to your knowledge, does sourceCpp work with Armadillo? Or do I otherwise have to reprogram `calc1` and `calc2` using say, blas? - I had been using var types such as `arma::mat`...

Comment: Of course it does. See the Armadillo examples at our just-launched [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) site.

Comment: Perfect! That site explains everything I needed clearly to me! Thanks!